# SP 2007 - Make picture library thumbnail unclickable

Tags: 2007, jquery, css, picture-library, thumbnail

SP 2007 / Moss: I have a picture library where I want to show the thumbnail in the list view but make it unclickable.  Right now when I click on it, it goes to the display form.

When I go into the picture library settings, there isn't a thumbnail column to edit.  I can't even see it in the Picture content type.

Could / Should I use CSS, jQuery or JavaScript to make the link unclickable?

Is there another way without resorting to code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No 2007 handy but depending on your browser coverage you can easily do that with CSS:

```
.ms-vb-icon a { 
    pointer-events: none
}
```

`.ms-vb-icon` is a sample selector from icons in document libraries, you need to identify how to target the column that contains the link with the thumbnail using your Web Developer Tools/Inspector.

https://jsfiddle.net/dmhLc3rx/

EDIT: jquery alternative

```
$(".ms-vb2 a").on("click", function(e) { 
    e.stopPropagation(); // this stops other click events from firing
    return false; // this stops the browser from following the href attribute
});
```

Comment: seems like .ms-vb-icon a is a class on the display form itself.  I was looking for it on the allitems page and found that .ms-vb2 a { pointer-events: none;}  does the trick.

Comment: turns out pointer-events doesn't work in IE.  do you know of a way to do this in javascript?

Comment: will update it, do you have jquery available?

Comment: Thats great! All I would have to do to use jquery is just reference the latest cdn right?